# Why can my group in SharePoint 2007 not be located?

Tags: permissions, groups

I have a SharePoint 2007 solution, that runs off FBA. I've created a new group called "Admin" and added all of my users who require administrative priviledges to this group.

During registration, I itterate all groups in SharePoint for the "Admin" group so I can e-mail them a notification of this new registration, but I keep hitting a "The group "Admin" does not exist in SharePoint." exception.

I've confirmed the existence of the group, unfortunately I cannot replicate this error on my local environment, just the deployed environment so cannot debug the process. I've deleted, and re-created the group, done an IIS reset and even stopped and started the Timer service.

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do You iterate through the groups? Using SiteGroups of the SPWeb instance? Have You tried oWeb.SiteGroups["Admin"]?

UPDATE:
web.Groups gives You only groups for this specific web. Loop through web.SiteGroups to get all the groups in the site colletion. You can also get group directly by calling web.SiteGroups["YourGroupName"]

Comment: hi zavaz, i'm looping through each group in web.Groups?